# Definition of Derivative and the Delta

Tags: approximation, analysis, calculus

I am doing some approximation for a function, during this task I came across the following equation and I was wondering if I can consider it as the derivative with respect to the variable $t$:
$$
\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x,t+ht)-f(x,t)}{h^2t}
$$
.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be $ht$ at the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, simple counterexample:

Let $f(x, t) = t$. Then

\begin{align*}
\frac{f(x, t+ht) - f(x, t)}{h^2 t} &= \frac{t+ht-t}{h^2 t} = \frac{1}{h} \overset{h \to 0}{\longrightarrow} \infty,
\end{align*}

but $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t) = 1.$

Comment: the limit goes to infinity, but still not equal and you are right.

Comment: Yes of course, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly. If $t\ne0$,

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x,t+ht)-f(x,t)}{ht}=\dfrac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}$$

and if $t=0$, the limit is $0$.